# Rendering a view from another MVC web-site

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, rendering, dynamic-compilation

mMy task is to create an action allows to get a downloadable copy of another asp.net MVC site output (let's think of it as a template and the result should be zipped collection of pages). 
The template site is located somewhere on the disk, but not inside the renderer site.
I.e. I want to load a view of another site and dynamically build it's output in current context.
I've solved a problem of locating a view by creation of custom VirtualPathProvider / VirtualFile and eventually the path is resolved correctly.
However, I have a compilation error in the code:

```
var engine = new EmbeddedViewEngine("My Custom Project", "Custom Site");
// Here goes the error.
ViewEngineResult viewResult = engine.FindView(this.ControllerContext, "Index", "", false);
```

Result:

```
c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\28ca69a5\2e195676\App_Web_index.cshtml.fb05bd29.4rma-j2y.0.cs(40)
: error CS0103: 
The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your Index view strongly typed?

Comment: No, there is no strong typing.